# glDrawElementsInstanced - model matrix not transfered correctly

Tags: opengl, lwjgl

I'm currently trying to teach myself some OpenGL using some Tutorials and LWJGL. Obviously I'm just at rendering cubes.

What I've done up until now, and what works is, that for each cube I'll do

```
glUniformMatrix4(RenderProgram.ModelMatrixID, false,
    renderobject.getTransformationBuffer());

glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, renderobject.Model.countIndices(),
    GL_UNSIGNED_INT, renderobject.Model.indexOffset);
```

Since that only gives me about 50-55 FPS with about 70k cubes, I decided trying instanced rendering, like so:

```
glDrawElementsInstanced(GL_TRIANGLES, Model.countIndices(),
    GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0, instanceCount);
```

Of course I've created another buffer for that beforehand, filling it with `renderobject.getTransformationBuffer()` of each cube and I'm binding this buffer before I try to draw instanced.

I also added it to my vertex shader like so `layout(location = 12) in mat4 mModel` and I've initialized the attrib pointers like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(12 + i);
    glVertexAttribPointer(12 + i, 4, GL_FLOAT, false, Float.BYTES * 16,
        Float.BYTES * 4 * i);
    glVertexAttribDivisor(InstanceBufferID, 1);
}
```

I get no errors and while I don't see anything on screen, it's rendering and I see an FPS increase of about 350% so I think that I don't get the right model matrix in the shader.

Unfortunately I can't debug variable contents within the shader :) So I'm a little bit stumped as to what I might be missing or how I could unravel this... Also, obviously, Google didn't help me much either and SO just comes up with `glDrawElements` not working for people.

**Edit:** The accepted answer was the one error that could be determined from the code provided. However, I had another error in the code, which needed fixing before finally something was visible on the screen, which I'd like to share as well: I unbound the VAO before populating the VBO with the matrix data. As soon as I pushed that unbinding after loading the data into the VBO it worked!

**Edit2:** Interestingly the performance increase is even more imense now that something IS rendered. With my blank screen I got around 170 FPS for around 70k cubes. Now that it renders correctly I'm getting around 350-400 FPS for around 270k cubes! I didn't expect that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument to `glVertexAttribDivisor` should be the index of the vertex attribute that you want to use as an *instanced array* and not `InstanceBufferID`.

This should thus become:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(12 + i);
    glVertexAttribPointer(12 + i, 4, GL_FLOAT, false, Float.BYTES * 16,
        Float.BYTES * 4 * i);
    glVertexAttribDivisor(12 + i, 1);
}
```

Comment: duh! of course... facepalm galore. Thank you, mate. I can only try that this evening but I'm very positive that you're right and will gladly accept this answer if it works :)

Comment: No problem, I'll await your response :)